# Non-Commutative Algebra book

Tags: book-recommendation, noncommutative-algebra

I am currently having a Master in topics such as Algebra, Geometry and Number Theory and recently I started studying Representation Theory where I've seen definition, theorems and propositions concerning rings that are non-commutative in general. I am wondering if there's any "standard" book(s) that can introduce me to the theory of non-commutative algebra.

Comment: Lam's "A First Course in Noncommutative Rings" and "Lectures on Modules and Rings" are both gems. (The former is the more introductory of the two, as the name suggests.)

Comment: I think I will go with "A First Course in Noncommutative Rings"  by Lam. Thank you Alex for your answer and I look forward for more book recommendations.

Answer (score 8):

Ones I have used extensively

- *First Course in Noncommutative Rings* by T.Y. Lam
- Isaacs *Graduate algebra*
- *Basic abstract algebra* by P. B. Bhattacharya, ‎S. K. Jain & Nagpaul

Others often mentioned as standard (but I did not really use)

- McCoy's *The theory of rings*
- Dummit and Foote's *Abstract algebra*
- Hungerford's *Algebra*
- *Noncommutative rings* by Herstein

Ones I have not used extensively but would recommend

- Lambek's *Lectures on rings and modules*
- Jacobson's *Basic Algebra* volumes I and II

Books that are a step up from an introduction

- Anderson and Fuller's *Rings and categories of modules*
- Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings*
- Louis Rowen's books and Carl Faith's books on algebra and ring theory.

Comment: A good method might just be to search for "Artin-Wedderburn theorem" in google books and just pick anything promising from the tons of hits that come back. That is a standard introductory topic in noncommutative algebra.

Comment: Wow, thats a nice collection to have. I will get as many of them as possible and look around while studying. Thanks rschwieb!

Comment: Studying Artin-Wedderburn theorem for representation theory was exactly the spark tha led me to search for more into Non-Commutative Algebra

Comment: If I  can make an addition, I'd say that Farb and Dennis' _Noncommutative_ _Algebra_ is pretty good as well. It's treatment of semisimplicity and the Jacobson radical are quite nice, and its approach to central simple division algebras is all based on going to the Brauer Group and seeing $H^2$ from a different light than the usual Galois cohomological perspective. They also focus on homological techniques, which are nice to see and useful if you're into $p$-adic representation theory.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, also added on my list. It is always nice to have many books on the same topic in order to see many different perspectives.